# css3 cursor and default shadow problems

Tags: html, css

So my cursor is still the default one even though I've changed it to pointer. As I was taking screenshots to post here I noticed if I hovered on the link and hit CMD it would change to a pointer but it would remain like that everywhere on the page unless I hit CMD again. My second problem is turning off the default shadow on an text input field. Ive tried box-shadow: none; but it didn't work. Im on a mac using safari 9.0.3[Default shadow on input element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92zw6.png)

```
form {
    width: 100%;
    input[type=text]{
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        height: 1.5vw;
        font-size: $fntSize;
        width: 12.7%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10.35vw;
        left: 68.3vw;
        box-shadow: none;
        cursor: text;
    }
    input[type=image]{
        position: absolute;
        top: 10.8vw;
        left: 80.1vw;
        height: 0.8vw;
        cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the issue with the cursor would be a lot easier with a jsfiddle that replicates the error on your end.

In terms of the default styling on the input, that's actually a `border` style not a `box-shadow`. The input defaults to `border-style: inset` so you just need to set your desired properties in its place. E.g. `border: 1px solid #ccc` or `border-style: solid` at a minimum.

Comment: thank you :) the border-style worked. Also loaded my project and it seems my cursor problem rectified itself, not sure how but Im not complaining.